# How to modify Teamcity artifact S3 storage upload path

Tags: teamcity

I want to publish my project build artifact to S3 bucket directly via Teamcity. To do so , I am using the  "Artifact Storage" in the left administrative panel.

[image]

I have linked the S3 storage to my S3 bucket. When I run the build, the artifact is uploaded to S3 but not to the target folder that I want.
For example if I want to publish **file.js** to **{My s3 bucket name }/{my Path}/file.js**, the end result is always **{My s3 bucket name}/{Teamcity Project name}/{Teamcity project Build Configuration Id}/{build number}/{my Path}/file.js**

Is there any way to configure the default target path creation to not include the Teamcity project details and only use the path I want?

Comment: I found a thread about the issue on JetBrains website. Unfortunately its status is: won't fix https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-52942